# Setting key in Entity class in android

Tags: android, jpa

I am trying to create an entity (using JPA with google datastore backend and using eclipse to generate end point class and libraries) where I want to use one of the fields(emailaddress) as the key. Please ignore the "Primary key" in my last post as I realised that's a JDO annotation but not JPA.

What I want to achieve is an entity where the Key is not generated automatically but I use a field(emailaddress which I know will be unique) as the Key. 
Can someone please confirm if the entity class I am writing is the right one. I am not able to insert a new entity hence checking the Entity class code. How to set emailaddress as the primary key and then insert a new entity using the emailaddress?

```
          //import statements

    @Entity
    public class UserTable {

      @Id private Key  emailAddress;
      private String userName;
      private String password;


      public UserTable() {}

      public String getUserName() {return userName;}
      public String getPassword() {return password;}


      public void setUserName(String userName) { this.userName = userName;}
      public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password;}
      }
```

Comment: Which is the error? Anyway, 2 quick checks: `@Id` should suffice if you are not doing anything peculiar, and using classes (instead of primitives/String) as `@Id` makes the implementation (and annotations) of that class (in this case, `Key`) relevant to the question.

Comment: Check `@IdClass` for the last point.

Comment: what is @PrimaryKey ? which JPA provider?

Comment: Thank you for our comments. I am editing my question to answer to the questions.